# A gap in a proof that if $N$ is a proper submodule of $M$ then length of $N$ is strictly smaller than length of $M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I was browsing those [online notes](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/de/AGR/CommutativeAlgebra/pp768-805.pdf) and in the first line of page $778$, it says something like:

> Since $N \cap M_{i} + M_{i+1}=M_i $ then, $N\cap M_i=N\cap M_i+N\cap M_{i+1}=N\cap M_i+M_{i+1}=M_i$

(Note that one of the equalities used an  inductive step that $M_{i+1}\cap N=M_{i+1}$).

The gap, as it seems for me is that, this argument assume that $A\cap (B+C)=A+B\cap A+C$, which is not true, even for vector spaces in general. And I don't see any justification for this step without using this assumption, which is invalid. So is that step correct? if yes, how to justify?

I tried to see if other forms of equalities that can turn this into a sound argument but found none.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that $M_i\supseteq M_{i+1}$, so $N\cap M_i\supseteq N\cap M_{i+1}$, so
$$N\cap M_i=(N\cap M_i)+(N\cap M_{i+1})$$
is true because for any module $A$ and submodule $B\subseteq A$, we have $A=A+B$.